# Webstorm Markdown editor tools all disabled?

Tags: editor, markdown, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm 2016.2.2 Build #WS-162.1628.41.  When I open a `.md` file I see a bunch of tools but they are all disabled.

[image]

How can I enable them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently <strike>Webstorm comes with</strike> at some point I had installed a trial version of a plugin called [Markdown Navigator from vladsch.com](http://vladsch.com/product/markdown-navigator).

I uninstalled it and now I get a couple basic buttons and a side-by-side preview.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK WebStorm does not contain any 3rd party trial plugins -- you must have installed that plugin yourself.

Comment: I really don't remember installing it, but I'll take your word for it.  Reworded answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to use the Markdown Navigator from vladsch.com, you need to activatie it by either a:

- [trial license](https://vladsch.com/product/markdown-navigator/try)
- [or buy a license](https://vladsch.com/product/markdown-navigator/buy)

and then add the license to the plugin via the settings to activate all of its functions...